# Difference between GSI ROMs

Tags: samsung, custom-roms, treble, gsi

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 8.0 (SM-T330NU) supported by Project Treble. It says the GSI is system-arm32-binder64-ab-vndklite.img.xz, but what I find [here](https://github.com/phhusson/treble_experimentations/releases) on GitHub is system-**squeak**-arm32-binder64-ab-vndklite-gogapps.img.xz.

Can I install that on the tablet or does it have to be that specific GSI?

Comment: It is not unusual that there are multiple custom ROMs.  As there are to my knowledge no official GSI images available you have to test which one you like more or which works better.

Comment: But if i install the wrong ROM my device might get bricked, although there isn't much difference between the roms they are both arm32 and binder64 and supports vndklite

Comment: When you start installing third-party ROMs, you have to accept that there's some risk you'll lose the device. Doing it on a device you rely on is brave.